# Where the System.StackOverflowException is occuring in my VB.NET quiz?

Tags: vb.net, stack-overflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZiS1.png)

The error seems to be occuring in the `Dim totalAdd, totalSub, totalDiv` and `totalMult` but this is weird as it worked just before and can not see where it could have gone wrong.

```
Public Class QuizForm
    Public Property Sign As String
    Dim Rnd1 As New Random
    Dim Rnd2 As New Random
    Dim Num1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
    Dim Num2 = Rnd2.Next(1, 10)
    Dim totalAdd = Num1 + Num2
    Dim totalSub = Num1 - Num2
    Dim totalDiv = Num1 / Num2
    Dim totalMult = Num1 * Num2
    Dim Score As Integer
    Dim Questions As Integer
    Dim prompt As String
    Private Sub QuizForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = Num1
        TextBox2.Text = Num2
        signLabel.Text = Sign

        If Sign = "+" Then
            answerLabel.Text = totalAdd
        ElseIf Sign = "-" Then
            answerLabel.Text = totalSub
        ElseIf Sign = "÷" Then
            answerLabel.Text = totalDiv
        Else
            answerLabel.Text = totalMult
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Checker_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Checker.Click
        If Sign = "+" Then
            If answerBox.Text = answerLabel.Text Then
                prompt = "Correct"
                Score += 1
                answerBox.Text = ""
            Else
                prompt = "Incorrect"
                answerBox.Text = ""
            End If


            Dim confirm As Integer = MessageBox.Show(prompt, "Answer", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            If confirm = DialogResult.OK Then
                Num1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
                Num2 = Rnd2.Next(1, 15)

                totalAdd = Num1 + Num2
                TextBox1.Text = Num1
                TextBox2.Text = Num2
                answerLabel.Text = totalAdd
                scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " & Score
            End If

            Questions += 1
            questionNum.Text = ("Question Number " & Questions & "/10")


        ElseIf Sign = "-" Then
            If answerBox.Text = answerLabel.Text Then
                prompt = "Correct"
                Score += 1
                answerBox.Text = ""
            Else
                prompt = "Incorrect"
                answerBox.Text = ""
            End If


            Dim confirm As Integer = MessageBox.Show(prompt, "Answer", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            If confirm = DialogResult.OK Then
                Num1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 15)
                Num2 = Rnd2.Next(1, 10)

                totalSub = Num1 - Num2
                TextBox1.Text = Num1
                TextBox2.Text = Num2
                answerLabel.Text = totalSub
                scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " & Score
            End If

            Questions += 1
            questionNum.Text = ("Question Number " & Questions & "/10")

        ElseIf Sign = "÷" Then
            If answerBox.Text = answerLabel.Text Then
                prompt = "Correct"
                Score += 1
                answerBox.Text = ""
            Else
                prompt = "Incorrect"
                answerBox.Text = ""
            End If


            Dim confirm As Integer = MessageBox.Show(prompt, "Answer", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            If confirm = DialogResult.OK Then
                Num1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
                Num2 = 2

                totalDiv = Num1 / Num2
                TextBox1.Text = Num1
                TextBox2.Text = Num2
                answerLabel.Text = totalDiv
                scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " & Score
            End If

            Questions += 1
            questionNum.Text = ("Question Number " & Questions & "/10")

        Else
            If answerBox.Text = answerLabel.Text Then
                prompt = "Correct"
                Score += 1
                answerBox.Text = ""
            Else
                prompt = "Incorrect"
                answerBox.Text = ""
            End If


            Dim confirm As Integer = MessageBox.Show(prompt, "Answer", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            If confirm = DialogResult.OK Then
                Num1 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)
                Num2 = Rnd1.Next(1, 10)

                totalMult = Num1 * Num2
                TextBox1.Text = Num1
                TextBox2.Text = Num2
                answerLabel.Text = totalMult
                scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " & Score
            End If

            Questions += 1
            questionNum.Text = ("Question Number " & Questions & "/10")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub menuButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menuButton.Click
        Dim quiz_menu As New MenuForm
        quiz_menu.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: which line exactly does the error message tell you is causing it? What debugging have you done? If it worked "before", then what did you change in between "before" and "after"?

Comment: See this is what I don't understand. The error message says "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll" and it is occuring when I declare my totals. The only thing i can think I have changed is adding a Log In form because it for students to use at the local primary school but I don't see how that would affect it. I have linked the image of what I am seeing for you.

Comment: if you are getting the full exception details including stack trace it will give you a line number. But I can see from your screenshot which line it is. Now, have you inspected your variable values to see if they are what you expected on that line?

Comment: where do I find the Line, because its not saying in the bottom of my screen what line?

Comment: you haven't expanded your exception in the UI to look at the details. But anyway it's stopped on that line so that's where it happens. (previously I didn't know you were seeing it in the IDE like that). Now you need to look at your variable values and see if they contain what you expect.

Comment: Yes the values are correct, When Num1 is 2 and Num2 is 2 totalMult is 4

Comment: Okay, it is something to do with the Log in form I have created as when I comment the whole form it runs perfectly fine. The only thing is, I can not see where it could have gone wrong.

Comment: if you show us the login form code we might be able to help you. Possibly it's doing something silly like creating endless copies of the quiz form or something. Infinite loops and similar logical errors are often causes of overflow exceptions since they can cause the app to run out of memory. Have you tried stepping through the login code to see how it is interacting with the quiz form?

Comment: Its okay now, i've found the problem. Thank you